# Can we add ports to OVS AFTER the VM is created?

Tags: virtualization, network-bridge

I wanted to write up a program where I can create VMs first using libvirt. Initially they would not be added to any network. Then I want them to be attached to an OVS bridge where I can specify the name of the virtual interface.

I have seen that openstack does something similar.

Is it possible to do so using libvirt and ovs commands?